# How formal is "cuán"? What are the informal alternatives?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios, formalidad

How formal is the Spanish word *cuán*? When is it appropriate to use, and when does it seem out of place? How are sentences using *cuán* normally expressed in informal speech?

Comment: +1 Nice question! I wanted to know that myself (shame on me Spanish is my native language :$)

Comment: I personally like 'cuán', but indeed it sounds a little sophisticated here (Argentina).

Comment: *Cuán* follows the same path as *whom* in English... in 20 years rom now nobody will use it.

Comment: Cuán indicates a quantity of something, tangible or intangible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spain, *cuán* is rarely used in normal, informal speech, though I think it would generally be understood.

To express the same, you can use *qué*, or *lo ... que*:

> ¡Cuán rápidamente caminan las malas nuevas! = ¡Qué rápidamente caminan
>   las malas nuevas!
>
> No puedes imaginarte cuán desgraciado soy = No puedes imaginarte lo
>   desgraciado que soy

In questions, in Spain, it is often replaced by *cómo de*:

> ¿Cuán grande es tu coche? = ¿Cómo de grande es tu coche?

But <s>**this usage is probably incorrect**</s>.

**NOTE**
Though the [definition by RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=cuan) doesn't say anything about the use of cuan in questions, the [DPD does](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=cu%E1n):

> Aunque no es frecuente, cuán puede aparecer también en enunciados
>   interrogativos

**UPDATE**
As @Gorpik comments, and [extracted from DPD (section 4.g)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=qu%C3%A9):

> **qué tan(to)**. Locución adverbial equivalente, según los casos, a
>   *cuán(to)* o a *cómo de*, que puede aparecer en oraciones interrogativas o
>   exclamativas, tanto directas como indirectas. Era normal en el español
>   medieval y clásico, y hoy pervive en amplias zonas de América

This also implies, in my opinion, that *cómo de* is also correct.

Comment: I strongly disagree with using it as **Cómo de**. I think it is incorrect. Do you have a source for it? Or are you a native spanish speaker so it may be a regionalism? :) Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't have any sources. I have always heard it as cuán, but it may well be incorrect. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure it is incorrect. It only sounds very bad. :)

Comment: Cuán, as in the example of the coche, could be replaced with "¿Qué tan grande..."

Comment: +1 "Cómo es de grande tu coche?" is accepted use in Argentina, actually the standard way; though it sounds slightly incorrect.

Comment: "Cuán grande es..." sounds unusual (too literary, almost poetic) but definitely correct to me. I am a native from Galicia, northwest Spain.

Comment: I use *Cómo de grande* as part of standard madrileño speech.

Comment: According to the DPD, all of those forms are valid: *qué tan(to)*. Locución adverbial equivalente, según los casos, a *cuán(to)* o a *cómo de*, que puede aparecer en oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas, tanto directas como indirectas. Era normal en el español medieval y clásico, y hoy pervive en amplias zonas de América.

Answer (score 5):

"Cuan" may be an unusual word for American-Spanish talkers but in Spain is quite common, at least in the "quantitative meaning" in questions. Other uses are not very very frequent and, usually, "cuan" is substituted by other structures (not by other words).

Cuan has two meanings that depend on the context, one of them is almost lost in the language.

1.- Cuan (in direct or indirect questions or in exclamations it should be written as "cuán"): Its meaning is "how much" or "how many" and it is a short form for "cuanto" (or "cuánto" in questions and exclamations). It is used when the word is just before an adjetive or and adverb ("cuan largo es", "cuan lejos vives") and never when you are making a comparison. It is very unusual to find it out of exclamations or interrogations but in old literature, and can be substituted by "todo lo".

Example:
"Corro cuan rápido puedo"-->"Corro todo lo rápido que puedo"

In exclamations, it is usually substituted by "qué" so you will not find it except in literature, especially in poetry.

Example:
¡Cuán bello es el amor!-->¡Qué bello es el amor!

In questions, is more frequent, although is not the most frequently used form to ask the size of something.
In Spain, it is very common to use "cómo de", and, in Latinoamérica, "qué tan".

Example:
¿Cuán largo es el vestido? --> ¿Cómo de largo es el vestido?//¿Qué tan largo es el vestido?

2.- Its second meaning is equivalent to "as" and introduces the second part of a comparison (as...**as**...). It is extremely rare, at least in Spain and in Mexico (I do not know other regions regionalisms), even in the literature. Almost always it is substituted by "como".

Example:
Tan alto cuan feo--> Tan alto como feo.

I hope I have helped, although it has been quite a long time since you asked the question. I apologize for my English.

Cuan: http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XzArprp97D66gn05Kb

Cuán: http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qsi2cT7VVD6TqNJhJC

Comment: +1 for the mentioning the *tan(to) ... cuan* structure

Answer (score 2):

In questions, "cuán" is equivalent to "qué tan":

> ¿Cuán rápido estamos caminando? = ¿Qué tan rápido estamos caminando?
>
> ¿Cuán bueno es ese restaurante? = ¿Qué tan bueno es ese restaurante?
>
> ¿Cuán lejos está la biblioteca? = ¿Qué tan lejos está la biblioteca?

In exclamations, "cuán" is equivalent to "qué":

> ¡Cuán rápido estamos caminando! = ¡Qué rápido estamos caminando!
>
> ¡Cuán bueno es ese restaurante! = ¡Qué bueno es ese restaurante!
>
> ¡Cuán lejos está la biblioteca! = ¡Qué lejos está la biblioteca!

"Cómo de" is a regionalism. I think outside of Spain it sounds very bad. In general, if you can use "qué", this will be the preferred form in the informal and formal speech. "Cuán" is more common in writing, especially in literature. I think using "cuán" is not formal; it's just not usual. My hypothesis is educated people use "cuán" more frequently, but it isn't related to a formality issue.

Comment: In Spain *qué tan* sounds wrong :) As you say, here we use *cómo de*. Both expressions are correct, according to the DPD.

Comment: Correct spanish should never use the `¿qué tan..?` it sounds as a "barbarism" adapted from english.

Comment: @eduyayo: according to who? `qué tan` is the only viable option in many places in latin america, in fact, `cómo de` might sound  completely ungrammatical. There's nothing inherently wrong about the phrase. This SE aims to discuss how Spanish is _used_ and **not** how it _should_ be used according to some arbitrary standards.

Comment: Not the only viable. As for correct is cuánto. According to all spanish speakers in Spain.

Comment: Spaniards only have a say within their own dialects. No one is forcing Spaniards to use `qué tan`, why should they be able to force anything on others? Something like `cuánto rápido estamos caminando` sounds ungrammatical to my ears, it's not an alternative. If you wanna continue this discussion, feel free to join the chat so we don't flood this answer with comments.

Comment: Nobody is forcing or whatever the thing you want to say about us the `spaniards` (By the way you´re not "latin" america as for Romans never reach there). If you speak wrong, you speak wrong. It does not matter where you are from. For example, "leismo" and "laismo" are well known wrong ways of speaking in some places here in Spain and wrong way of speaking in most or all Mejico. And it is wrong per se. Nobody imposes people the correct or incorrect way. They just do it wrong the standard way... But wrong. Please, Read more. Hate less.

Comment: Una pregunta del tipo `¿Cómo es el paquete?` (u otro objeto) puede ser ambigua en cuanto a las características que se desean conocer (forma, tamaño, color...); `¿Cómo es el paquete de forma y tamaño?` es una forma válida de formular la frase especificando. Si sólo se requiere una característica, también vale `¿Cómo es el paquete de tamaño?` y si se presupone que es pequeño `¿Cómo es el paquete de pequeño?` o bien `¿Cómo de pequeño es el paquete?`

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't really what you were asking about, maybe it's worth mentioning that it would be somewhat out of place to use *cuán* when you're in Mexico, where it is far more common to say *qué tan*.  For example,

> ¿Qué tan lejos está el Zócalo?

or

> ¿Qué tan grande es?