# Translating "How (much)" in non-numeric situations

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

How do you translate "How (much)" when asking about non-numeric properties?

For example:

"How bright is that light?"

"How hard was the exam?"

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1279/376

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***cuán***:

> How bright is that light? => ¿Cuán brillante es esa luz?
>
> How hard was the exam? => ¿Cuán difícil fue el examen?

However, it is a formal word and sometimes affected.
It will always be more normal to make a periphrasis:

> ¿Es muy brillante esa luz? ¿Cuánto brilla esa luz?
>
> ¿Fue muy difícil el examen? ¿Cómo estuvo el examen?

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it wrong to say: ¿Cómo brillante es esa luz? And what about: ¿Qué tan difícil fue el examen?

Comment: The second one is wirght and the first one is worng, you can said instead: ¿Cómo de brillante es esa luz?

Comment: Also worth noting that _qué tan_ == _cuán_

Comment: @MaríaCC _cómo de brillante_ sounds agrammatical to me. Where are you from?

Comment: @clinch Do _qué tan_ and _cuán_ have equivalent formal connotations?

Comment: @clinch I'm from Spain. "Qué tan" is sonds weird to  me too, are latin?

Comment: @quienquilo I would say not, but these things tend to be regional. _cuán_ is almost invariably in the formal registry/in the prestige dialect, in every other scenario, _qué tan_ would be the way to go.

Comment: @MaríaCC interesting! yes, I'm in Latin America. Didn't know _cuán_ felt unnatural to Spaniards. Maybe other Spaniards should confirm that (since there's regional differences within Spain as well)! ^^

Comment: Cuán is not at all strange to me, in fact it seems to me that it is more correct accurate form. But informally I would say Cuánto de brillante es?

Comment: @MaríaCC oops, i meant _qué tan_, my bad. I didn't know _qué tan_ was weird in Spain.

Comment: @I suppose that's because we never use "qué" to ask for quantities or characteristics. But surely it's only a matter of countries differences :P

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cuán` or `qué tan`:

> ¿Qué tan brillante es esa luz?
>
> ¿Qué tan difícil fue el examen?

You can also use `cómo` + ser:

> ¿Cómo es de brillante esa luz?
>
> ¿Cómo fue de difícil el examen?