# How to make reference to *extent* in a declarative statement?

Tags: pronombre-interrogativo

In English, we can make reference to *extent* with "how." [Translating “How (much)” in non-numeric situations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/11811/translating-how-much-in-non-numeric-situations) deals with a similar, but not identical question.  Note that it focuses on *questions* and I would like to focus on *statements*.  Also note that most of the answers there revolve around *qué tan*, which is not used in Spain, and I am looking for forms familiar in Spain.

An example of a sentence that I would have difficulty translating to Spanish is

> Last night showed how agreeable his personality is.

In Spanish questions, we can use forms like:

> ¿Qué/Cuánta valor tienen estas películas?

and

> ¿Hasta qué punto son valiosas estas películas?

Comment: I fail to see how this question is different from the one you link, or how those answers don't provide an answer to this. I would answer this question pointing to "cuán", "cómo" (¿Cómo de valiosas son estas películas?) Could you please clarify the difference with the linked question?

Comment: Anvyne and @Gorpik, could you please check my edit to the question to make sure it fits with both of your understanding of what's being asked?  (Gorpik, I think when a question is in danger of being closed, and you intuit, better than the close-voters, how the question is different from the duplicate, you're supposed to edit the question to make things clearer....)

Comment: Im tempted to vote Close, but i'll hold my review vote for the Original asker to make the changes suggested by @aparente001. Also, i would kindly ask other reviewers with "close votes" to allow some time for the Asker to edit the question into a valid non-duplicate form, if -of course- you feel it appropriate. Skipping for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a usual construction that can only be used in declarative sentences like this, but not in interrogative ones. In Spanish we can use the neuter article *lo* to turn an adjective into a noun, with a quantitative meaning in this case. So you can use this construction:

> La pasada noche demostró lo agradable que es su personalidad.

Or even:

> La pasada noche se vio lo agradable de su personalidad.

You can also use the same constructions as for questions, of course:

> La pasada noche se vio cuán agradable es su personalidad.
>
> La pasada noche se vio cómo de agradable es su personalidad.

Or, in American countries:

> La pasada noche se vio qué tan agradable es su personalidad.

Comment: Perhaps also: La pasada noche demostró hasta donde llega su amabilidad?

Comment: @aparente001 That changes the original too much, in my opinion.

Comment: also i think the "to an extent" can be simplified to be translated to "que tan/tanto" instead of "hasta que punto"

Comment: @Gorpik - okay, it's your answer.

Comment: @Mike - For some questions, sure, but I don't think it works for this one: "¿Qué tanto son valiosas estas películas?

Comment: @aparente001 you are right "tan" and "tanto" are more complicated to use

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary answer to Gorpik's (which I support).

Also:

> Anoche se demostró hasta donde llega su amabilidad.
>
> Anoche se pudo ver hasta qué grado llega su amabilidad.
>
> Anoche se pudo ver el extento de su amabilidad.
>
> Anoche se pudo ver lo amable que es [fulano].

(*Fulano* is a stand-in for the name of the person you're referring to.)

Although you didn't ask for alternative phrasings of questions, I'll offer this to help you see how it can be helpful to forget about *translating* and concentrate instead on getting the *idea* across:

> ¿Cuál es el valor de estas películas?