# How + adjective construction

Tags: traducción, gramática

En un restaurante anoche quería preguntar al mesero `How big is __`, pero no sabía la manera de decirlo. Mi amigo español no sabía tampoco, pero dijo que se puede decir `Cuán grande` (formal), `Cómo de grande` (incorrecto) o `Qué tamaño tiene...` ¿Cuál de ellos debería usar?

También quisiera una construcción más general para `How [adjective] is ...`. Por ejemplo, `How interesting was the lecture?` o `How bad can it be?`.

¡Gracias! Otros consejos bienvenidos.

Comment: ¿Cómo de grande? está perfectamente bien dicho. No sé porque te habrá dicho que no.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-formal-is-cu%C3%A1n-what-are-the-informal-alternatives) hay una discusión sobre el tema. Aunque la pregunta original es específicamente sobre *cuán*, las respuestas incluyen tambien "cómo de", "qué tan", "qué"...

Comment: @MikMik Ya he leído esa pregunta, pero allí también dice que "cómo de" no es apropiado. Debido a que hay varias opiniones sobre la tema, supongo que quiero clarificar la validez de cada frase.

Comment: La otra pregunta dice que cómo de es informal, pero es una forma equivalente y de uso bastante panhispánico. Pero a contraste del inglés, el castellano suele preferir preguntas con verbos, es decir, en vez de *¿cómo de / qué tan / cuán alto es?*, la gente preferiría *¿cuánto mide?*, o sustantivos que implican gradación como *¿de qué altura es?* o pidiendo la unidad de medida directamente *¿de cuántos metros es?*. Pero como hablante no nativo, cualquier de las formas se entenderán si las usas (hablo de *cómo de/qué tan*) aunque no se suela usar en una zona particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como @guifa ya mencionó, las opciones ya propuestas por tu amigo español son precisamente lo que yo sugeriría. Cuando tu amigo dijo que era algo "incorrecto" se refería seguramente a que no pertenece al [registro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstico) formal del idioma en España.

A veces las personas mezclan algo que en realidad no es permitido por la gramática del idioma, y algo que simplemente es informal. Es importante hacer notar que esto último es completamente correcto y seguramente lo encontrarás en muchos textos a pesar de no ser formal, por lo que es importante aprenderlo.

Las alternativas entonces son (todos estos seguidos del adjetivo):

- *cuán*: Pertenece al registro formal, poco a poco cae en desuso (análogo a e.g. *mas*).
- *qué tan*: Pertenece al registro informal, una formulación hasta cierto punto regional debido a su falta de uso en España.
- *cómo de*: Pertenece al registro informal, también regional ya que no es usada fuera de España.

También es importante hacer nota de que estos podrían cambiar de registro conforme evolucione el idioma. En mi dialecto particular, *qué tan* es tan aceptado en contextos formales como *cuán*.

Algunos ejemplos:

> - ¿Qué tan alto eras cuando eras niño?
> - ¿Cuán grande era tu primer apartamento?
> - ¿Cómo de vieja es esta leche?

Comment: La RAE cita (pero no sé del uso contemporáneo a no ser hablante rioplatense) *cómo de [adj]* en el rioplatense, pero a diferencia de lo que suelo usar yo, con el verbo intercalado entre *cómo* y *de* (es decir, *¿cómo es de grande el niño?*). Quizás algún argentino o uruguayo podría aclarar.

Answer (score 3):

`Qué tan [adj]` funciona para muchos adjetivos. Grande, pequeño, caliente, frío, cerca, lejos... Todo lo que se pueda cuantificar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constructing it in a manner parallel to English, I'd probably express it using a different verb. Depending on the context, the verb chosen could vary. For example, "How big is..." could be "Cuánto mide...". In the context of a restaurant, and if you're talking about how big a portion of food is for a given plate, I might say "Es mucha comida para una persona..." or "Son porciones grandes...". Also, as others have touched on, in my non-native ear it sounds fine to say "Cómo es de grande..." or "Cómo es de tamaño...".