# ¿Qué tan adecuado es usar "en tanga" en un escrito formal?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, formalidad, deportes

Hace unos días leía la noticia de fútbol [El Madrid gana de milagro a un PSG muy superior](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/11/03/champions/1446583699_695229.html) y me sorprendió ver esta frase:

> **En tanga todo el primer acto**, el Madrid se fue de ejercicios
>   espirituales al descanso en ventaja, con un gol por el que no se
>   hubiera jugado los cuartos ni el madridista más entusiasta del
>   planeta.

El Real Madrid jugó una primera parte muy mala. De ahí que "en tanga" aquí se refiera a algo así como "indefenso", "sin mayor fuerza", "con pocos recursos".

Me sorprende que esta expresión esté presente en una redacción de un periódico "serio". Por tanto, me pregunto: ¿qué tan adecuado para este contexto es usar la expresión "en tanga"? ¿está usando el tanga (esa ropa interior tan minúscula) para formar una imagen mental de la vacuidad o tiene alguna otra interpretación?

---

He encontrado otros artículos del mismo periodista (José Samano, de prosa muy buena) en que también utiliza esta expresión:

- [El ‘Maracanazo’ fue una broma](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2014/07/08/mundial_futbol/1404827346_653023.html)

> Brasil era muñeco de trapo. La afrenta iba a más, sin remedio para **un
>   grupo de futbolistas en tanga**, con las gentes llora que llora en las
>   gradas...

- [Papá, no quiero ser defensa](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/10/11/actualidad/1444591570_518153.html)

> Su sospechosa revolución contracultural acabó por pulir **una
>   retaguardia en tanga** con el principal sostén de un tipo rechoncho y de
>   movimientos paquidérmicos llamado Ronald Koeman, al que solían
>   escoltar dos auxiliares sin talla como Ferrer y Sergi.

- [España sufre un descalabro mundial](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2014/06/13/mundial_futbol/1402677430_078624.html)

> Holanda se vengó con saña de la derrota de hace cuatro años en
>   Sudáfrica y con Robben al frente **dejó a España en tanga**, como un
>   muñeco de trapo a merced de un adversario que en el segundo tiempo fue
>   la marabunta. No hubo español reconocible.

- [¿Está el presidente?](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2015/09/01/actualidad/1441124933_419495.html)

> Ocurre algo peor, **De Gea queda en tanga** ante el técnico que le condenó
>   en pretemporada y ante una hinchada que, pese a los tiempos de
>   infieles a las camisetas, aún pide una gota de devoción.

Comment: Daría para otra pregunta, pero aprovecho: el uso de "Qué tan + adjetivo", ¿es común en  alguna zona concreta hispanohablante? A mí me suena muy raro y diría siempre "Cómo de + adjetivo", pero buscando en google veo que es bastante común.

Comment: @machlas ¡interesante! No había caído en la cuenta. La verdad es que en España se usa con frecuencia, si bien no sabría decir si predomina sobre "Cómo de + adjetivo". Tal vez sí sería interesante consultarlo en otra pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui No diría que "qué tan" es común en España, la verdad. Es mucho más común "cómo de". Al menos por donde yo me muevo. Por cierto, [ya se comenta en otra pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1279/376)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"En tanga" para un escrito formal es totalmente inadecuado. A mi entender, nunca uno se refiere a las prendas interiores en un escrito formal, y menos con una expresión como "en tanga" con su clara connotación de inferioridad haciendo referencia al pasivo en una relación sexual. Uno podría argumentar que se refiere a que los agarraron desprevenidos, pero uno diría que los "pillaron en paños menores", "encontraron en calzones", etc., no haciendo referencia a ropa interior femenina.

En el fútbol este tipo de expresiones son muy comunes entre hinchadas. Los diarios deportivos relajan la formalidad y se permiten este tipo de frases hasta cierto punto.

Comment: Quizá porque ya esté acostumbrado a estas expresiones en este contexto, pero a mí no me parece nada inadecuado. También es que el registro de un periódico en crónicas deportivas dista mucho de lo que yo entiendo por un escrito formal.

Comment: Creo que estamos hablando de lo mismo. La frase en sí no me sorprende a mi tampoco por el contexto, pero si la leyera en algún mail de mi jefe, me parecería inadecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Para mí gusto es inadecuado. Pero esas noticias que pones son del periódico deportivo Marca, que se caracteriza por su falta de seriedad y rigurosidad. Además que el periodista use tanto esa expresión demuestra que le faltan recursos.

Comment: No, no son del diario Marca sino de El País. Estoy de acuerdo con que el Marca es especialmente poco serio y riguroso, si bien tiene algún periodista bueno (léase Santiago Segurola).